# System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot use a DependencyObject that belongs to a different thread than its parent Freezable

Tags: wpf, dispatcher

I have this problem... but can't figure out where is coming from.
Do you know of a way to debug this? This happens in a WPF application that has several windows each running in different dispatchers.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot use a DependencyObject that belongs to a different thread than its parent Freezable.
   at System.Windows.Freezable.EnsureConsistentDispatchers(DependencyObject owner, DependencyObject child)
   at System.Windows.Freezable.OnFreezablePropertyChanged(DependencyObject oldValue, DependencyObject newValue, DependencyProperty property)
   at System.Windows.Media.RenderData.PropagateChangedHandler(EventHandler handler, Boolean adding)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RenderClose(IDrawingContent newContent)
   at System.Windows.Media.RenderDataDrawingContext.DisposeCore()
   at System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.ArrangeElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.ArrangeElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Window.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
   at Syncfusion.Windows.Shared.ChromelessWindow.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisualAndUpdateSTC()
   at System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double requestedTop, Double requestedLeft, Double requestedWidth, Double requestedHeight)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow)
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at Djali.Services.WindowInfo.PreloadWindow() in c:\src-tfs\Development\Djali\Djali\Services\GuiThreadsService.cs:line 612
   at Djali.Services.GuiThreadsService.<>c__DisplayClass20.<InitializeRuntime>b__11() in c:\src-tfs\Development\Djali\Djali\Services\GuiThreadsService.cs:line 293
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Comment: *Why* do you have several dispatchers, and what does your code in `GuiThreadsService` look like?

Comment: It's a real time application which needs to have the GUI very responsive. That's why there are several dispatchers. The GuiThreadsService just keeps track of all the dispatchers and handles things like Invoke in the correct dispatcher. Nothing out of ordinary.

Comment: I would say that using multiple dispatchers *is* out of the ordinary, and it looks like it's *not* handling things in the correct dispatcher in the code in question. If you use asynchronous operations or background threads appropriately, I wouldn't expect you to need multiple dispatchers to keep the UI responsive - just make sure that the *one* dispatcher is kept appropriately available.

Comment: It's true that multiple dispatchers is out of the ordinary. Each window has a grid with a lot of changes (throttled every second). Using multiple dispatchers do seem to make a difference. But I take your point that it's a hack. Thanks Jon.